# Java getter vs this

Tags: java

This is a very generic scenario, where I am setting a variable using setter function and using the variable only locally.

```
class Main {
 private String str;

 public Main(String value)
  setStr(value);
 }

 private String getStr() {
    return str;
 }

 private void setStr(String str) {
    this.str = str;
 }

 public void display() {
    //METHOD1
    System.out.println(getStr());
    //METHOD2
    System.out.println(this.str);
  }
}
```

1. What would be the better practise to follow between the two METHOD1/2 in display function, basically what would be the better way of using "str" variable.
2. Does it even make sense to have private getter/setter functions?

   - Ivard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the getter is private, and doesn nothing more than returning a private variable, it isn't needed, IMHO (i.e. I prefer the second method of accessing it).

But if the getter was public and not final, and could thus be redefined by a subclass, then you'd have to decide if you want to get the potentially overridden value returned by the getter, or if you want the value of the private field in the display method.

Answer (score 2):

Here should be at least one comment with **Yes**.

By providing new *abstraction barrier* you can separate data *accessors* and data *presentation*.   For example, lets look  at *complex number* class. Which can be implemented as

```
class ComplexNumber {
    private final double realPart;
    private final double imaginaryPart;

    ComplexNumber(double realPart, double imaginaryPart) {
        this.realPart = realPart;
        this.imaginaryPart = imaginaryPart;
    }

    public double getRealPart() {
        return realPart;
    }

    public double getImaginaryPart() {
        return imaginaryPart;
    }
}
```

or in *polar expressions* form

```
class ComplexNumber {
    private final double r;
    private final double angle;

    ComplexNumber(double r, double angle) {
        this.r = r;
        this.angle = angle;
    }

    public double getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public double getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }
}
```

Presume that you should implement basic operation like +-/*. What presentation model should you choose? For addition and subtraction standard model preferable, but for multiplication and division polar form preferable. So you can create getters for both form. And implement *add*/_sub_ like you have standard model and *div*/_mult_ like with polar form. This operation wouldn't depend from your actual data presentation. For change presentation you should change getters. Thats all. In Java world it's called *self encapsulation*.

Comment: Huh, what should your `sin/cos` representation be? The usual polar representation is (radius, angle), and it can be converted to the cartesian form by applying sin and cos on the angle and multiplying the result with the radius. And normally `int` is not a good datatype here, even more if you want to convert between the representations.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann,  int was just for example. With polar representation - it's my bad, of course radius and angle. Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Better now, but I would still recommend changing your int to double, to have a more realistic example.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a side effects in your ***public*** getter which you desire I would consider always using `this` for consistency unless inheritance is assumed.

It doesn't make sence at all to me to employ ***private*** accessors. A routine should typically only do *one* thing and preferably without side effects. Creating a private getter

- **without** side effects only creates useless redundancy.
- **with** side effects basically proves that either the method is doing too much or is poorly named

---

Using `this` might also make refactoring easier [1].

[1] Refactoring a private variable gives less impact than refactoring a method. If you later decide to change the contract, e.g., by no longer providing a *getter* routine you will get less to refactor. Besides, many editors *highlight* all occurences of a variable when pointing the cursor to it, which is lost when hiding its use in a sub-routine.

Answer (score 1):

1. For simple cases you'd just use `this.str`. For more complex cases, you might want to inherit from such a class, and have getStr() be implemented in a subclass perhaps it would lazily get the string from a file/database. Then these methods would't be private though.
2. For trivial cases where you just assign and fetch a private member, not really. For more complex cases where you might need to do additional logic, it'd make sense to confine that logic to one place. As with 1., it would make sense if you want sub classes to override the methods as welll.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not useful to have private getter/setter methods.  If they were public or otherwise overridible by subclasses though it would be a different story.  Should a subclass override your getter/setter, it could change the way the `display()` method functions.